# Ember ActiveModelAdapter errors in custom save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm overriding the success and failure of my model's `.save` so I can do some authentication of a user after creating the record. Unfortunately, this is not populating the template with the errors object that `ActiveModelAdapter` typically populates for you. How can I restore the default error handling behavior here?

```
UsersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    create: ->
      self = this
      email = @get('email')
      typedPassword = @get('password')
      user = this.store.createRecord 'user',
        email: email,
        password: @get('password')
      user.save().then( (->
        self.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:custom',
          identification: email
          password: typedPassword
        )), (error) ->
          # error => InvalidError https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js#L86
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this on the Route and not the Controller helped me solve this:

```
UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    return @store.createRecord('user')
  actions:
    save: (user) ->
      self = this
      typedPassword = user.get('password')
      user.save().then( (res) ->
          self.get('session').authenticate('ember-simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant', {
            identification: user.get('email'),
            password: typedPassword
          })
        , (res) ->
          # no-op
      )
    willTransition: (transition) ->
      user = @get('currentModel');
      user.deleteRecord()
)

`export default UsersNewRoute`
```